# pandas lambda with multiple arguments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume there is a DataFrame such as

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[21, 11, 31, 45],
                   'B':[10, 20, 10, 11],
                   'C':[57, 22, 34, 10]})

    A   B   C
0   21  10  57
1   11  20  22
2   31  10  34
3   45  11  10
```

I would like to write a function that can be used with lambda such as

```
def WeightedScore(x, probs):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(probs)):
        total += x[i]*probs[i]
    return total

df ['out'] = df.apply(lambda x: WeightedScore(x['A'], x['B'], x['C'], probs = (0.2, 0.3, 0.5)), axis = 1)
```

But I got an error something like this

```
TypeError: WeightedScore() got multiple values for argument 'probs'
```

Any suggestions? many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are passing multiple arguments here:

```
df.apply(lambda x: WeightedScore(x['A'], x['B'], x['C'], probs = (0.2, 0.3, 0.5)), axis = 1)
```

You probably meant something like:

```
df.apply(lambda x: WeightedScore([x['A'], x['B'], x['C']], probs = (0.2, 0.3, 0.5)), axis = 1)
```

But you shouldn't be using `.apply` here to begin with. Instead, use vectorized operations:

```
df['out'] = ((0.2, 0.3, 0.5) * df).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are passing **multiple arguments** where your  `WeightedScore(x, probs)` expects only **2**, so instead pass only the `x`, That's why you are getting-

> TypeError: WeightedScore() got multiple values for argument 'probs'

You can do it this way,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[21, 11, 31, 45],
                   'B':[10, 20, 10, 11],
                   'C':[57, 22, 34, 10]})

def WeightedScore(x, probs):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(probs)):
        total += x[i]*probs[i]
    return total

df ['out'] = df.apply(lambda x: WeightedScore(x, probs = (0.2, 0.3, 0.5)), axis = 1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    A   B   C   out
0  21  10  57  35.7
1  11  20  22  19.2
2  31  10  34  26.2
3  45  11  10  17.3
```